# Can twisted pair replaced by two wires which are closely placed?

Tags: i2c, differential, twisted-pair

If I have differential signal wires, can I place **two wires closely 1mm-2mm** gap between them **but not twisted**? (1mm or 2mm gap is fixed it won't change from place to place )

I am using [Differential I2C modules](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/qwiic-differential-i2c-bus-extender-pca9615-hookup-guide)

because having a twisted wire in the application is not possible

how bad this will affect the signal?

are there any other issues with the above setup?
[example](http://www.doublejumpelectric.com/projects/imu_noodle/2017-05-28-imu_noodle/)

*edited*

**I2C communicate through cables long-distance up to 10ft-20ft**

**There is no noise from motors or magnetic fields around my application**

**I can use very thin cables (<1mm) in my application**

Comment: Depends on how critical the twisted pair in the first place. If it was (i.e. your environment was really noisy), then you probably can't get away with doing what you are suggesting.

Comment: Using a range extender and then **not** using TP is the same as carrying wood into the forest.

Comment: @Janka  http://www.doublejumpelectric.com/projects/imu_noodle/2017-05-28-imu_noodle/ if you refer this they have not used twisted pair

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you don't need the range extender then either. Single-ended I²C is good for at least one metre. If you limit the data rate, you can go a few metres.

Comment: @Janka in my case, I have to go up to 10ft-20ft, there is no noise from motors or magnetic fields around my application

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use TP? Is it because of flat cables? There are TP flat cables; bigger SCSI hard disk towers used them for example.

Comment: What I2C speeed you are targeting? 100 or 400 kHz clock?

Comment: @Justme  I am targetting 400Khz

Comment: Try it and see if it works. It probably will. Look at the signal with a scope to make sure it is good, or if you don't have a scope, then use a double length cable. If it works reliably in a double length cable, then you know you have some design margin with the single length cable.

Comment: I'm on the side of "you have a good chance of making this work".  While twisted pairs, or even shielded twisted pairs would be a more ideal arrangement, if your environment is fairly benign (as you claim), you should be OK.

Comment: Do you have the option to put an overall shield around the differential cables?  I know this can get ugly in a multi-drop topology, but thought I should suggest it anyway.

Comment: @SteveSh no I cannot use a shield, I can use very thin cables (<1mm) in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old fashioned telephone wires went tens if not hundreds of feet without twisting: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.tes.com/lessons/tAdaFtDFdyTSqg/telephone-poles).

Usually, at each pole, a particular single wire pair was positionally reversed to avoid a build up of cross-talk between all the simultaneously utilized phone lines but, in-between poles they were all parallel. So, if your bandwidth is low and your distance is moderate, and your signal-to-noise ratio expectations are low to medium and you have little chance of interference from high frequency magnetic fields then try out non-twisted pair cable.

Answer (score -1):

***Differential input*** and ***twisting*** solve different tasks, which are ***subtraction*** of the two voltages and ***homogenization*** of the electromagnetic field, respectively.

The first of them is more important because it ensures the mutual destruction of induced disturbing voltages, while the second only equalizes the two voltages making the result of the subtraction closer to zero.

So if your perturbing electromagnetic field is homogeneous enough, you can forego the twist. But as others have said, only experiment will tell if this is the case.